# Highland add to stream before being completely consumed?

Tags: javascript, stream, highland.js

Exist a way to add to an stream of highland an ended message with a full description of our needs?

Less suppose we have the following situation:

```
const stream = high([1,4,6,7])
```

Then with this stream, I want to count each one of the values being processed and say

```
sink.drain(stream.pipe(4))
```

Being 4 the number of elements of the array. Consider that could be thousends of objects in an stream and I need to consume from the stream in order to be able to count.

I cannot say array.length because it is a source that could come with any information, and that information is being processed with the stream... How can I add to the stream a Message End with the description of what was consumed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to set up some state around your values, but without hindering the consumption of your values. I would suggest looking at some solutions that involve `h.through`.

You could split a stream with `fork` or `observe` and reduce some state from the values:

```
h([1, 2, 3, 4])
  .through(stream => {
    const length = stream.observe()
      .reduce(0, m => m + 1)
      .map(length => ({ length }))

    return h([stream, length])
      .sequence()
  })
  .errors(err => console.error(err))
  .each(x => console.log(x))
```

You could create some state and return a new stream based on the events of the source stream:

```
const h = require('highland')
h([1, 2, 3, 4])
  .through(stream => {
    let length = 0

    return h(push => stream
      .tap(() => ++length)
      .errors(err => push(err))
      .each(x => push(null, x))
      .done(() => {
        push(null, `length: ${length}`)
        push(null, h.nil)
      }))
  })
  .errors(err => console.error(err))
  .each(x => console.log(x))
```

Comment: thanks for the help, at the end the stream was being deliver to a queue of messages, so I end up creating a "an end message" during the creation of the pipe, that I filled up with the stream during the execution of the stream. Later I had to run a second stream with the collected information... as it was a queue the order of the messages remain... as you stated a new stream with the collected information